# How to resolve this TypeScript error: "Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2"

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, lint

I'm writing Node.js code in JavaScript (not TypeScript) but use the TypeScript static analysis tool to check my JavaScript.

I have the following JavaScript code that uses the [stampit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stampit) library:

```
import stampit from 'stampit'

const Character = stampit({
  props: {
    name: null,
    health: 100
  },
  init({ name = this.name }) {
    this.name = name
  }
})

const Fighter = stampit(Character, { // inheriting
  props: {
    stamina: 100
  },
  init({ stamina = this.stamina }) {
    this.stamina = stamina;    
  },
  methods: {
    fight() {
      console.log(`${this.name} takes a mighty swing!`)
      this.stamina--
    }
  }
})
```

I've installed the [DefinatelyType package for stampit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/stampit).

However, I got the following error and it applies to the whole `stampit(Character, {...})` function call:

```
Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2
```

Any ideas how to resolve this error?  Even just turn it off using TypeScript?

Comment: " Even just turn it off using TypeScript" -> Ignore it with `//@ts-ignore`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** It seems like it's a bug in @types/stampit.  It might work with TypeScript without issues, but has issues with writing JS code. The issue can be resolved by changing the `stampit` declaration to:

```
declare function stampit(f1?: stampit.Stamp | Options, options?: Options): stampit.Stamp;
```

The type definitions [are for stampit v3.0.x](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/stampit/index.d.ts#L1), whose most recent release was [3.0.6 two years ago](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stampit?activeTab=versions), so (assuming you freshly installed stampit v4.1.2) the definitions are out of sync with the code & documentation. Your options are:

1. (strongly discouraged) Use stampit version v3.0.6 (`npm i -S stampit@3.0.6`)
2. Write updated type definitions for stampit v4.1.2 (and, hopefully, create a pull request against the DefinitelyTyped repository)
3. Add `//@ts-ignore` everywhere you get an error, as vibhor1997a said
4. Explicitly treat the library as untyped: `const stampit: any = require("stampit");`

#2 is the best, obviously, since it also benefits anyone else who wants to use the library. If you don’t have the time or inclination to do that, I would advise against #3 because it’s error-prone and tedious. That leaves #4, which at least forces you to be explicit and vigilant.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed comment.  I tried suggestions 1) and 2) and they did not work (it looks like @types/stampit is activity developed).  However, I see that the there is an issue with @types/stampit.  I have changed the `.d.ts` file for now.  I hope to commit it to the repo, or raise an issue at some stage.  My change is `declare function stampit(f?: stampit.Stamp | Options, options?: Options): stampit.Stamp;`